# chaining jobs in hadoop: Type Mismatch

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I want to map -> reduce -> map -> reduce

Here's what I want to do:

I have this input tsv file:

```
1   2
2   1
2   3
3   2
4   2
4   3
```

After my first map/reduce job, I have this

```
1   0
2  -1
3  -1
4   2
```

And after my 2nd map/reduce job, I have this (output file)

```
2   1
-1  2
0   1
```

Except that my code compiles but for the 2nd job, I have this error

```
Error: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in value from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable, received org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
```

And I don't understand since I do not send Text for values to my 2nd job
Here's my full code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import java.io.IOException;

public class problem {

 public static class DiffMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    Text key = new Text();
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private final static IntWritable minus = new IntWritable(-1);

    public void map(Object offset, Text value, Context context)  throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString(), "\t");

        while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
            if(itr.countTokens() % 2 == 0) {
                key.set(itr.nextElement().toString());
                context.write(key, one);
            }

            else {
                key.set(itr.nextElement().toString());
                context.write(key, minus);
            }
        }
    }
 }

  public static class DiffReducer extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)  throws IOException, InterruptedException {

      int sum = 0;
      for (IntWritable val : values) {
        sum += val.get();
      }
      result.set(sum);
      context.write(key, result);

    }

  }

 public static class CountMapper extends Mapper<Text, IntWritable, IntWritable, IntWritable> {

    IntWritable key2 = new IntWritable();
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);

    public void mapCount(Text offset, Text value, Context context)  throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString(), "\t");

        while (itr.hasMoreElements()) {

            String node = itr.nextElement().toString();
            Integer diff = Integer.parseInt(itr.nextElement().toString());

            key2.set(diff);

            context.write(key2, one);

        }
    }
 }



  public static class CountReducer extends Reducer<IntWritable,IntWritable,LongWritable,IntWritable> {
    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    public void reduceCount(LongWritable key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)  throws IOException, InterruptedException {

      int sum = 0;
      for (IntWritable val : values) {
        sum += val.get();
      }
      result.set(sum);
      context.write(key, result);

    }

  }



  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf1 = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf1, "problem");
    job.setJarByClass(problem.class);
    job.setMapperClass(DiffMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(DiffReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    Path outputPath = new Path("Diff");

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outputPath);
    outputPath.getFileSystem(conf1).delete(outputPath);
    job.waitForCompletion(true);
    //System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);



    Configuration conf2 = new Configuration();
    Job job2 = Job.getInstance(conf2, "problem");
    job2.setJarByClass(problem.class);
    job2.setMapperClass(CountMapper.class);
    job2.setReducerClass(CountReducer.class);
    job2.setOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
    job2.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    Path outputPath2 = new Path(args[1]);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job2, outputPath);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job2, new Path(args[1]));
    outputPath2.getFileSystem(conf2).delete(outputPath2, true);

    System.exit(job2.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, all mappers will use `TextInputFormat`. The key therefore is a LongWritable and the value is Text.

Your error is from the fact that you've set IntWritable as the value instead.

Your second mapper is no different than the first, so the definition of both  mappers needs to be `extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text`

Also, method names `mapCount` and `reduceCount` means nothing to mapreduce. The method names must be `map` and `reduce` accordingly, and you should add an `@Override` annotation to let the compiler know that method overwrote the Mapper class. Along with that point, the parameters `Text offset, Text value` needs to be `LongWritable offset, Text value`. Also make sure the Reducer has the correct method parameter types.

You already are parsing the lines back to integers inside the method body with `Integer diff`

Worth pointing out - Your Reducers are the exact same. You therefore only need one class for both mapreduce stages